# Filter descendants parent [or at least higher level than results]

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Still a Linq newbie here, and now having issues with the WHERE clause. I'm trying to return anything found in the **printer** tags, but only from below the element **list** *type="lff"*.

If I try to output the descendant elements with no WHERE clause, I get everything (from both `<list>` elements). When I try to add various versions of a WHERE clause, I get nothing back. I'm obviously not putting the WHERE condition in correctly.

(I need to get the element object, so I can check the NAME and the VALUE. In my example below, I am only outputting the VALUE for now).

Can you advise?

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<printerlist>
  <list type="aff">
    <printserver>print-server1</printserver>
    <printserver>print-server2</printserver>
    <printserver>print-server3</printserver>
    <additionalprinters>
      <printer>
        <fullname>\\servera\bbb</fullname>
      </printer>
    </additionalprinters>
  </list>
  <list type="lff">
    <printserver>print-sever4</printserver>
    <additionalprinters>
      <printer>
        <fullname>\\serverb\bbb</fullname>
      </printer>
      <printer>
        <fullname>\\serverc\aaa</fullname>
      </printer>
    </additionalprinters>
  </list>
</printerlist>
```

And here is the code to try and get the list:

```
var qq = from c in xml.Descendants("additionalprinters").Descendants("printer")
//where (string) c.Parent.Attribute("type") == "lff"
//Uncommenting the above line means that nothing is returned.
select c;
foreach (XElement q in qq)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test Output: {0}", q.Value );
}
```

Output is:

```
Test Output: \\servera\bbb
Test Output: \\serverb\bbb
Test Output: \\serverc\aaa
```

I am only looking for the final two outputs to be returned, in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent of `printer` is `additionalprinters` and it doesn't have `type` property, you need to use `.Parent` twice to get  `list` element.

```
from c in xml.Descendants("additionalprinters").Descendants("printer")
where (string) c.Parent.Parent.Attribute("type") == "lff"
select c
```

Or you can also do the following

```
xml.Descendants("list")
.Where(c => (string) c.Attribute("type") == "lff")
.SelectMany(x => x.Element("additionalprinters").Descendants("printer"))
```

Comment: Oh, my understanding of Parent has been wrong. And I didn't know you could use Parent.Parent... GREAT! Yeah, I need to move to lambda at some point, but I'm still learning. Works great, thank you. (Need to wait 4 mins to mark as ans).

Comment: Also, +1 because of concise info about where the parent was actually pointing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use XPath selector from System.Xml.XPath namespace for this purpose:

```
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var printers = doc.XPathSelectElements("//list[@type='lff']/additionalprinters/printer");
```